# Procedure different tables into IF

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I want to select a table according to the value received per parameter. Would there be possibility of doing it similar to my code? Thank you.

/*PROCEDURE */

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE text varchar(30);

    IF (type = 1) THEN  
        SET text = 'table1';
    ELSEIF (type  = 2) THEN
        SET text = 'table2';        
    ELSEIF (type  = 3) THEN
        SET text = 'table3';        
    ELSEIF (type  = 4) THEN
        SET text = 'table4';                
    END IF;

    Select * from text where `fee type` = var2;

END
```

Comment: Google "mysql prepared statements"

Comment: That you're trying to do this strongly suggests that your schema violates the [principle of orthogonal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  Better to have a single table, with an (indexed) column that contains an indicator (e.g. the string `'table1'` etc) that distinguishes the data according to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is concatenated with the name of the table and used in the PREPARE.

/*PROCEDURE */

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE text varchar(30);

    IF (type = 1) THEN  
        SET text = 'table1';
    ELSEIF (type  = 2) THEN
        SET text = 'table2';        
    ELSEIF (type  = 3) THEN
        SET text = 'table3';        
    ELSEIF (type  = 4) THEN
        SET text = 'table4';                
    END IF;

    SET @s = CONCAT('Select * from ',text,' where `fee type` = ?')
    PREPARE sentence FROM @s;
    SET @var1 = 2;
    EXECUTE sentence USING @var1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE sentence ;

END
```